# 'AddView' object has no attribute 'render_to_response'

Tags: django

*my view.py* is:

```
class AddView(BaseCreateView):
    template_name = 'add.html'
    model = Classname
    fields = '__all__'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.reverse('sitepro:list', kwargs=[])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = ClassnameForm
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(AddView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

---

I'm not getting what it want to say as I have `included render_to_response`. Please anybody help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import `render_to_response`, instead use `self.render_to_response` since it's inherited from`BaseCreateView`.

[This](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a great resource for Class Based Views.